# Moving to Eclipse Indigo for Android development

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-3.6

I am at present using Eclipse Helios (3.6.2).
I am using it for Android development.

Is there any reason to move up to Indigo?
What are the gains vs the pains.

If yes, which of the multitude of Eclipse installations do I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works without problems for me. *Eclipse Classic* or *Eclipse IDE for Java Developers* should do it.

As for benefits: I didn't see major changes, just some small improvements. I get newer versions to have some bugs fixed. If you want to know more, the eclipse doc has some changelogs for various components, e.g. see the [java section](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.7-201106131736/eclipse-news-part2.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'd not advise to move to Indigo. It's very raw, at least on Windows. From Anddev perspective it's just a Helios with many bugs: some weird problems with breakpoints, hangs when you try to see contents of complex variables, even strings, doesn't mark with red files with errors. One day in Indigo was enough for me to move back to Helios (while it seems to work better on my Mac - don't know is it possible - but I mostly use Eclipse on Windows machine). I tried to use Juno also - awful, even more bugs, extremely raw.

Maybe somebody got better experience, but Eclipse Indigo in my case (Android dev) is not a variant.

Comment: I have been using Janus for some time now. The only major problem I had was with the Copy/Cut/Paste screwing up. They finally fixed that and now all seems to be ok.

Comment: I think Helios is quite enough for now.